# Unification in first order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, automated-theorem-proving, unification

I know unification problem in first order logic is defined as a equation $t_1=s_1, ..., t_n=s_n$.
My question is that why unification in first order logic can not be defined as a unification of a formula?
Why should unification in first order logic be limited to unification of first order terms?
In first order logic, when unification is defined as a equation, it does not consider unification of formula which contains quantifier. In this case, why unification type of first order logic is unitary?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear: what do you mean by "unification type of in first order logic is unitary". That said, there is no problem in extending the notion of unification from first-order terms to first-order formulas, but it doesn't add anything interesting, because in first-order formulas there are no propositional or predicate variables, so unifiable formulas have to be structurally identical until you get down to the term level and quantifiers just restrict the allowable variable substitutions.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.
Would you please explain what if we add propositional variables to first order logic?

Comment: If you add propositional  variables then you have moved in the direction of higher-order unification and that is a complex subject. You need to ask a more specific question.

Comment: Why higher order unification? I do not intent to substitute functional symbols by new substitution.
for example, what are unifiers $\forall x(f(x)---->X)$ where f is unary function symbol, x is a bounded variable and X is a free variable or propositional variable.

Comment: Once you allow propositional variables you are outside first-order language and you need to ask a much more specific question about the problem you want to solve.